# format transfered value with contracts decimals

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have the amount of transfered tokens converted from a transactionreceipts log data.

for example USDT the value I got is 500000000 , USDT has 6 decimals. The actual transfered value is only 500 USDT, how can I convert that using web3 or javascript to use the contracts decimals and output the correct value?

Would amount / math.pow(10, tokendecimals) be the correct way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you should use a library like ethers.js https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-utils.html

**utils . parseUnits** ( valueString , decimalsOrUnitName )   =>   BigNumber
Parse the valueString representation of units into a BigNumber instance of the amount of wei. The decimalsOrUnitsName may be a number of decimals between 3 and 18 (multiple of 3) or a name, such as gwei.

**utils . formatUnits** ( wei , decimalsOrUnitName )   =>   string

Answer (score 0):

I built a simple tool that does this, called [evm-bn](https://github.com/paulrberg/evm-bn). Here's how you could use it to format 500 USDT:

```
import { BigNumber } from "@ethersproject/bignumber";
import { toBn, fromBn } from "evm-bn";

const decimals : Number = 6;

const amount : BigNumber = fromBn("500000000", decimals) // amount = "500"

const amount2 = toBn("500", decimals) // amount2.toString() = "500000000"
```

The `evm` stands for Ethereum Virtual Machine, while `bn` for "big number". The second parameter is optional; it defaults to 18 decimals.

Note that this was designed to be used alongside [@ethersproject/bignumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethersproject/bignumber). The ethers package is a peer dependency.